# Cheat engine выдает другой базовый адрес в отличие от Module.BaseAddress

Tags: c#

```
Process proc = Process.GetProcessesByName(name)[0];

foreach (ProcessModule module in proc.Modules)
{               
    if (module.ModuleName == "server.dll")
    {
        int i = (int)module.BaseAddress;
        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + module.ModuleName + "   BaseAddress: " + Convert.ToString(i, 16));
        BaseAdd = (int)module.BaseAddress; // эта функция берет базовый адрес модуля(536d0000)
    }
}
```

С помощью этого кода я получаю базовый адрес модуля, но он отличается от "server.dll" в cheat engine.
Также я заметил, что я получаю адрес, который находится в "редактор памяти -> просмотр -> список загруженных dll и символов."

[image: Как видим адреса у них одинаковые]

Я хочу получить адрес "server.dll" в окошке ниже (он равен: 35F1878C). К "server.dll" прибавляем 009858DC

[image: То что я хочу получить в красном квадрате]

Comment: Каждый раз, когда вы запускаете приложение сервера, адрес в памяти будет новый.

Comment: Для работы с адресами в памяти используйте IntPtr, а не int.

Comment: хорошо, поменяю на IntPtr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня получилось решить эту проблему. Для это нужно установить библиотеку VAMemory(https://vivid-abstractions.net/logical/programming/vamemory-c-memory-class-net-3-5/). Подключаем её и инициализируем

```
VAMemory vam = new VAMemory("hl2"); // "hl2" вместо этого нужно вписать название процесса к которому подключаемся.

        {
        Process proc = Process.GetProcessesByName(name)[0];
        int ID = proc.Id;

        IntPtr handle = OpenProcess(0x001F0FFF, false,ID);

        foreach (ProcessModule module in proc.Modules)
        {               
            if (module.ModuleName == "server.dll" || module.ModuleName == "hl2.exe")
            {
                BaseAdd = vam.ReadInt32((IntPtr)(module.BaseAddress + 0x009858DC)); // вот самый нужный метод. 0x009858DC это смещение, которое было выше. Каким-то магическим образом оно находит нужный адрес, который находит CE(последняя картина). Не знаю как оно работает, но оно работает!
                Console.WriteLine("Name: " + module.ModuleName + "   BaseAddress: " + Convert.ToString(BaseAdd, 16));
            }
        }
        }
```